# Cross Directive Functional Binding in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

In an angular 1.5 application, both directive are independent inside *same* application
A demo of the situation shows here
https://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/qXRGQp

You will see an error where in componentA, its component's function that suppose to bind to componentB's function was not found. I wonder if there is way I can bind the function in two different directive without go through the main application?

If I have to go through main application, what is the most optimal way of doing so?

Js

```
var app = angular.module('github', []);

app.directive('componentB',() => {
  return {
    scope: {
      updateA: '=',
    },
    template: `<div> B </div>`,
    controllerAs: 'componentBCtrl',
    controller: () => {
      this.callMePlz = (newVal) => {
        console.log('hehe');
        console.log(newVal);
      }
    }
  };
})

app.directive('componentA',() => {
  return {
    scope: {
      updateA: '=',
    },
    template: `<div> A </div>`,
    controllerAs: 'componentACtrl',
    controller: () => {

 console.log('a is running');     this.updateA('madness');
    }
  };
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="github">
  <!-- compA has a change take places which trigger a change of value in compB  -->
  <component-a
    update-a="componentBCtrl.callMePlz"
  >

  </component-a>

  <component-b>


  </component-b>

</div>
```

Comment: use '&' to bind functions to directives, don't use '='. Also, I don't think this is the best approach as it kinda breaks the whole reason of having different components that encapsulate their functions. Maybe you could explain a little more of what you are trying to do and we could come up with a better approach?

Comment: @Ero `it breaks the whole reason of having different components that encapsulate their functions` interesting thinking. I could have done by broadcast / on as well, but that was even more confusing for others to debug. the purpose is really the clearest I can explain here. maybe I can rephrase. -` its to call a directive's function inside another directive without creating an umbrella controller in angularjs application`. Does that sounds more... clear?

Comment: Put the shared behavior into a service and inject it into the controller for both directives.